# Error Syntax error: "(" unexpected en una línea

Tags: bash

Estoy ejecutando un script en un sistema Rasbian y en una linea en concreto me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
/scripts/backup_mysql.sh: 16: /scripts/backup_mysql.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

El fichero es el siguiente:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 # CRONTAB (every hour)
  4 # 0 * * * * sh -x /scripts/backup_mysql.sh >> /logs/cron_backup_mysql.log 2>&1
  5 
  6 touch /logs/backup_mysql.log /logs/cron_backup_mysql.log
  7 
  8 DATE=`date +"%d%m%Y%H%M"`
  9 echo " ${DATE} ---------------------------------------"
 10 
 11 DATA=$(date +%d%m%Y_%H%M)
 12 
 13 . /scripts/db_connect
 14 
 15 declare -a BBDD=('db_rpi02' 'db_rpi02_wordpress')
 16 
 17 for DB in "${BBDD[@]}"; do
 18         START_TIME=0
 19         START_TIME=$SECONDS
 20         NAME="$(hostname -s)-${DB}-${DATA}"
```

En la linea 16 no tengo nada por lo que intuyo que será la anterior.

La ejecución se inicia mediante crontab:

```
0 * * * * sh -x /scripts/backup_mysql.sh >> /logs/cron_backup_mysql.log 2>&1
```

Que problema hay con los paréntesis?

Gracias!

Comment: En linea 13, debe ser un espacio entre . y / ?

Comment: esta bien. cargo unas variables.

Comment: no es reproducible el error. Necesitaríamos saber en qué sistema corre todo esto, etc.

Comment: Una pregunta como "está enchufada" ha guardado el script?  (Es decir, lo que vemos es lo que arranca?)

Comment: he añadido mas información. El sistema donde lo ejecuto es Rasbian, y la ejecución del script lo hago mediante cron

Comment: Y linea 8 es correcto tambien?  Con los "backticks" en lugar de ' ?

Comment: Comprueba la versión de bash que tienes en el raspbian y el que tienes donde te funciona el script. Me da que es cosa de la forma de declarar el array de la línea anterior

Answer (score 0):

He usado finalmente **bash** en lugar de **sh** en la ejecución via crontab. Gracias!

Comment: Super que lo hayas resuelto con `bash` en lugar de `sh` (enlace directo a `dash`). Pero nota como en el inicio de tu script inicias con `#!/bin/bash`, lo cual es bueno, pero hace innecesario indicarle al crontab el programa, ya que dentro del script se lo indicas. Mejor dale permisos de ejecución con `chmod +x <programa>` y luego en tu crontab pon `0 * * * * /ruta/completa/a/tu/programa.sh >> etc 2>&1`.

Comment: si, lo que pasa que le añado el "-x" para poder ver todo el proceso.